# how to check if strings of an array are on page pure js

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

Trying to make a chrome extension where if certain words are on the feed/page it'll print a message in console

heres my current code:

```
// Checking page title
if (document.title.indexOf("Twitter") != -1) { 

//Checks if selected text is on page
if (document.documentElement.innerText.indexOf('enjoys') > -1) {

//if selected text is on page, print this
console.log("it works!");
} else { 

// if selected text is not on page, print this
console.log("selected text is not on page");
}
} else {

//if not on twitter print this
console.log("title is not twitter");
}
```

this code works fine but it's limited to only one word which, as you can see above, is currently the word **enjoys**. I want to change it so that I can replace the one word with an array with several words/strings.

so lets say I have the array spoiled:

```
var spoiled = ["terrible", "hit", "pain"];
```

I want my extension to check if all those words in spoiled are on my twitter page.

in **pure JS**, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate, and use `every()` to check for all the words

```
var spoiled = ["terrible", "hit", "pain"];

var result = spoiled.every(function(word) {
    return document.documentElement.innerText.indexOf(word) > -1;
});

if (result) { // all exists }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a TreeWalker to search all the text nodes.